Dask erring on GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV
I am trying to train an xgboost model using dask. I already have the data transformed andhave prepared my data as follows:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)

and i am able to do a simple model fitting to the data like this:
model = dxgb.DaskXGBRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.score(X_test, y_test)

But when i try anything more complex. like using dask's gridsearchcv like this:
param_grid = {
'max_depth': [3, 8],
'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1]}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(
model, param_grid)

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

i get the following warning:
WARNING:dask_ml.model_selection._search:('daskxgbregressor-fit-score-f6830e79aeb606b3eed291ac24184a8c', 1, 1) has failed... retrying

and in the task graph everything is black from erring.
Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Oh yes, that's just a typo i did when asking the question

Can you run the example from https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html using the built-in iris dataset? Or does that also error/fail?
